# weird behaviour when parsing json coming from php in javascript

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a weird problem with parsing a JSON response coming from php source (symfony2). This is probably something very trivial but I'm not very skilled in javascript so have lost many hours on this already.

I have a serialized php-array in my db, which I unserialize and then convert to JSON.

```
$response->setContent(json_encode(unserialize($onderdeel->getArticles())));
```

On the client I just use jQuery to parse the json data.

```
$.ajax({
   ......
    success: function(data){
        articleObject = jQuery.parseJSON(data); 

        }
    });
```

However this gives me some weird results, some of the values are set to undefined while they should have a value. However some of the values are ok.

This is the raw result I get from the php script before it get's parsed:

```
   {
       "onderdeel":{
          "onderdeel_id":"1546",
          "onderdeel_type":"overgordijnen160",
          "onderdeel_naam":"",
          "onderdeel_opmerkingen":"",
          "berekend_prijs":"0",
          "status":"",
          "active_artikel_id":"0",
          "naam_ruimte":"",
          "opmerkingen":""
       },
       "artikels":[
          {
             "ruimte":"",
             "opmerkingen":"",
             "korting":"",
             "berekend_aantal_banen":"2",
             "aantal_banen_zelf_ingegeven":"",
             "berekend_hoeveelheid":"400",
             "berekend_multiplicator":"1.9",
             "berekend_valide":"",
             "berekend_prijs_met_korting":"0.00",
             "berekend_prijs":"20040040.00",
             "stap2":{
                "valide":"valide",
                "hoogte":"100",
                "breedte":"100",
                "banen":"stel",
                "stof":{
                   "id":"9",
                   "naam":"AGRA",
                   "modelnummer":"123456",
                   "stofbreedte":"140.00",
                   "rapporthoogte":"100.00",
                   "kleur":"nul",
                   "prijspermeter":"100.00",
                   "wasvoorschriften":"COOL WASH COOL IRON",
                   "stock":" "
                },
                "railtype":{
                   "id":"7",
                   "naam":"rails type 1",
                   "modelnummer":"RT-2",
                   "stock":"200.00 stuks",
                   "rapporthoogte":"null",
                   "prijspermeter":"null",
                   "wasvoorschriften":"null"
                }
             },
             "maakwijze":{
                "status":"",
                "maakwijze_type":"lint",
                "plooi":"",
                "retour_plooi":"",
                "cm_plooi":"",
                "hoofdje":"100",
                "berekende_string":"LINT > gewone voering",
                "voering_string":"gewone voering",
                "voering":{
                   "voering_id":"",
                   "voering_prijs":"",
                   "voering_onderdeel":"",
                   "voering_type":""
                },
                "voering_aan":"true",
                "confectie":{
                   "confectie_id":"2",
                   "confectie_prijs":"10000000.00",
                   "confectie_zoom":"25.31",
                   "confectie_onderdeel":"OG < 160",
                   "confectie_type":"LINT > gewone voering"
                },
                "valide":"valide",
                "loodjes":"loodjes"
             },
             "prijs":{
                "prijs_valide":"",
                "prijs_korting":"",
                "prijs_plaatsing":"",
                "prijs_berekend_voor_artikel":"",
                "prijs_berekend_voor_artikel_met_korting":"",
                "prijs_berekend_stofprijs":"40000",
                "prijs_berekend_confectieprijs":"20000000",
                "prijs_berekend_prijslood":"40",
                "prijs_berekend_voering":"0",
                "prijs_railtype_prijs":""
             }
          }
       ],
       "onderdeel_naam":"",
       "onderdeel_opmerkingen":""
   }
```

However after I parse it this is the result:

[image: javascript object from parsed json]

For example artikels.0.maakwijze.maakwijze_type is set to undefined while in the raw json it is set to 'lint'.

The weird thing is that if I just copy the raw json to the chrome console and parse it with the same function jQuery.parseJSON('copied text') all values are ok

I also replaced the jQuery.parseJSON with the standard JSON.parse , but this gave me the same result

Any ideas what causes this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you do anything to the data after you parse it?

Answer (score 3):

> On the client I just use jQuery to parse the json data.
>
> ```
> $.ajax({
> ......
>     success: function(data){
>         articleObject = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
> ```

If your server is returning `Content-Type: application/json`, `data` will **already** be a parsed object. You don't want to parse it again.

*Without* the `jQuery.parseJSON(data)`, it [works for me](http://jsbin.com/atuhem/1) ([source](http://jsbin.com/atuhem/1/edit)).

Comment: Alternatively, simply supply `dataType: json` incase the server isn't sending the headers, and it will be automatically parsed.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: Yeah. Although really, the server should be supplying the correct content type.

Comment: a 100% agreement from my end; but just in case!

Comment: thanks! but this didn't make any difference. After some more tests it seemed that the values getting undefined only happened when I set async: false as a setting in the ajax call. However if I remove this the object isn't set properly and next steps in script flow will give an error. Any solution to this? Or is there a design pattern or something for these kind of situations?

Comment: @joskes: As you can see from the example in the answer, this *does* work. The problem you're having lies in code you haven't quoted. You'll need to create a [small, self-contained example](http://sscce.org) that replicates the behavior, and people will be able to help you see what's wrong.